# Suppress filename print in fswatch

Tags: ubuntu

Is it possible to have `fswatch` prints only the event time in the output?

I am using it as follows"

```
fswatch . -t --event Updated -e ".*" -i "\\.txt$"
```

In the directory I am working with, I have only one `txt` file and I wanted to have the time at which it is modified. `fswatch` does an amazing job for me. I am wondering if I can suppress printing the filename somehow since the current directory has a very long name which is appended to the event time and makes it a long line.

Can `fswatch` only prints the event times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `--format` allows you to have a custom `printf`-like output.

```
fswatch . --format %t --event Updated -e ".*" -i "\\.txt$"
```